# appcelerator cant update new version of app - missing armv6

Tags: ios, sdk, appcelerator, armv6

i have to update old app

if i try to validate it, validator says that architecture armv6 is missing.

i have xcode 4.5.2  and titanimum 3.1.0.201304151600

in titanium when i click on Distribute - Apple iTunes Store i have only option to select SDK Version 6.0

i am using Titanium SDK 2.1.3 GA. in builder.py for this Titanium SDK is condition, that if i am using ios sdk version >= 6.0  then armv6 is not available.

so i am not able to upload app to appstore.  when i build project via titanium and then look on it in xcode, there is only armv7 in settings.  if i add there armv6, app is not validated correctly.

is there way how to add different ios sdk to titanium?  i tried to install different iOS simulators in xcode under preferences -> download (but probably this has no effect on it).

any advices what should i do to validate app ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you update your xcode and titanium ? maybe it will solve lot of troubles !
If you need to publish for ios 6.1 try to install last xcode 4 version copy the sdk from folder (MAC) content/developer/platforms/iphoneIosPaltform and copy the ios 6 sdk.. then install xcode 5 and paste the sdk in the same folder... then you got sd6 and sdk7 options in titanium. Download the 6.1 simulator with xcode

Hope this will help you . !

Comment: when you are updating app, it needs to support all devices which has previous version of app supported. updated xcode and titanium does not support armv6 architecture.